# Does ethereum support something like bip32 extended public key?

Tags: wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp, accounts, addresses, public-key

Bitcoin and Litecoin have something called `XPUB` key or `Extended Public Key` that essentially allows to track all generated public addresses, so think monitor your total balance in one key.

I was trying to see if ethereum has something like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. This is typically how the **[Mnemonic code for generating deterministic keys (BIP39)](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki)** protocol works.

**The user generates a 12/24-word Wordlist, eg:**

> power foster height puppy palm swing slight rain hammer expire inquiry picnic

**The Wordlist is then used to generate a seed.**

> 89e86df183f51db7d2b827b489b612a6f544fe7f8168bdaba62b3fbf2f16c291e0076a55b96b613cadca8d253b98fc31988ac6e7fce52e567cdc393dc6c89cb9
>
> This seed can be later used to generate deterministic wallets using
> **[BIP-0032](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki)** or similar methods **[BIP-0044](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki).**

Ethereum deterministic wallets work the same as they do in Bitcoin or Litecoin. When specifying **`path`** parameter, simply increment the **`address_index`** to create as many accounts as you like:

> m/44'/60'/0'/0/**0**
>
> m/44'/60'/0'/0/**1**
>
> m/44'/60'/0'/0/**2**

Comment: When the path is represented as m/44..., it means it is a BIP 44 path, not BIP 32.

Comment: The registered coin types for BIP 44 can be found at https://github.com/satoshilabs/slips/blob/master/slip-0044.md

Comment: @bitsabhi thank you for pointing out my mistake. So would Bitcoin's value be `m/44'/0'/0'/0/0`?

Comment: Yes, m/44'/0'/0'/0/0 represents the BIP 44 path of the Bitcoin address.