# Generate Ethereum address using Bitwasp/BIP32 library

Tags: hd-wallets, bip32

I am new in cryptocurrencies.
I am using `PHP` library `Bitwasp/Bitcoin-lib` (https://github.com/Bit-Wasp/bitcoin-lib-php) to generate addresses for bitcoin. I am validating my outputs [here](https://iancoleman.io/bip39/). I was successful to generate `Bitcoin`, `Litecoin` and `Dogecoin` addresses which the BIP32 class in the library supports. [iancoleman](https://iancoleman.io/bip39/) is generating `ethereum` addresses too with BIP32 protocol. How can I do that? I have debuged the code and I found that there are some lines on the top of `BIP32.php` file which shows the coins that this class supports.

```
// Bitcoin
public static $bitcoin_mainnet_public = '0488b21e';
public static $bitcoin_mainnet_private = '0488ade4';
public static $bitcoin_mainnet_version = '00';
public static $bitcoin_testnet_public = '043587cf';
public static $bitcoin_testnet_private = '04358394';
public static $bitcoin_testnet_version = '6f';

// Dogecoin
public static $dogecoin_mainnet_public = '02facafd';
public static $dogecoin_mainnet_private = '02fac398';
public static $dogecoin_mainnet_version = '1e';
public static $dogecoin_testnet_public = '0432a9a8';
public static $dogecoin_testnet_private = '0432a243';
public static $dogecoin_testnet_version = '71';

// Litecoin
public static $litecoin_mainnet_public = '019da462';
public static $litecoin_mainnet_private = '019d9cfe';
public static $litecoin_mainnet_version = '30';
public static $litecoin_testnet_public = '0436f6e1';
public static $litecoin_testnet_private = '0436ef7d';
public static $litecoin_testnet_version = '6f';
```

I know these are magic bytes. What are these values for `ethereum` or other coins like `Bitcoin-cash`? How can I find these values?
I found that It is possible to generate ethereum address using BIP32 [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28815/does-ethereum-support-something-like-bip32-extended-public-key). But I don't know how?